# Ionic Framework Routing Issues

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

I am creating an App in ionic but I am stuck in routing issues. Currently I have an app view with a side menu and on Home page I have two tabs `Tab 1` and `Tab 2` which have different UI Views `tab1.html` & `tab2.html`

[image: App View]

**Tabs Code in `home.html`**

```
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light hp" tabs-style="tabs-icon-top" tabs-type="tabs-positive" style="top: 60px !important;" animation="slide-left-right">
      <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/home/tab1">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab1-content"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Chats Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Tab 2" href="#/home/tab2">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab2-content"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

**`tab1.html` and `tab2.html` code:**

```
    <ion-view view-title="Tab 1">
        <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="false" class="has-header">
            Tab 1 Content
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>

    <ion-view view-title="Tab 2">
        <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="false" class="has-header">
            Tab 2 Content
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

**Routing Code in 'routing.js'**

```
    .state('menu.home', {
        url: '/page21',
        views: {
          'side-menu21': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
          }
        }
    })

    .state('menu', {
        url: '/side-menu21',
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        abstract:true
      })

    .state('menu.about', {
        url: '/page10',
        views: {
          'side-menu21': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
            controller: 'settingsCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
    ... and so on
```

**Issue:**

When I navigate Home from menu or from login page (which is separate) I didn't see tabs' content. Can anyone help me what's wrong?

**The page url seems like:** `http://localhost/testapp/#/side-menu21/page21`

Your assistance in this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add *abstract* property in home tab state :

```
.state('menu.home', {
    url: '/page21',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 abstract states, one for a side menu, and one for Tabs itself, if you can create a plunkr/codepen of what you have I could be able to help you.